# What is the scale of the MeanDecreaseGini in R randomForest package?

Tags: r, random-forest

the Gini index is a score that varies from 0 to 1, however, in my experience, the MeanDecreaseGini in R's randomForest package is several fold larger than this range. My naive assumption is that if the Gini index ranges from 0 to 1, the mean decrease in the Gini index for a given variable should also be within this range. I haven't been able to find if this score is scaled (eg. mean decrease x 1000). Can someone please tell me if MeanDecreaseGini has been scaled, and if so what that scale is, or is my interpretation completely wrong?

Thanks,

Sam

Comment: The values given in `fit$importance` are unscaled, while `importance(fit, scale=TRUE)` supposed to do scaling. I could not make it work though(for binary classification).